# [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209) Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/unknown Given String is empty or null

Tags: flutter

i am trying to create a login sign up with firebase i can sign up and data comes firestore but when i try to login with same user i cant login what can i do can someone help me

E/flutter (20570): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/unknown] Given String is empty or null
E/flutter (20570): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (20570): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:177:18)
E/flutter (20570): 
E/flutter (20570): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:377:43)
E/flutter (20570): 
E/flutter (20570): #3      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:474:12)
E/flutter (20570): 
E/flutter (20570): #4      FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:550:7)
E/flutter (20570): 
E/flutter (20570): #5      AuthService.signIn (package:untitled4/auth.dart:10:16)
E/flutter (20570): 
E/flutter (20570):

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword() requires two parameters, String email and String password. I think Flutter is telling you one of these is empty when you call the method. Make sure the parameters are set via the TextEditingControllers().

```
TextField(
  controller: emailCtrl,
),
TextField(
  controller: passwordCtrl,
),
FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailCtrl.text, passwordCtrl.text);
```